# Using responsive iframe within jQuery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So i'm trying to add a responsive iframe to the inside of a dialog box..

Here is my starting point:   [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/0L5t42pg/4/) which simply shows a button that on click displays an iframe.  The iframe however isn't responsive and doesn't resize with the page.

Using the guidance from [here](https://blog.theodo.com/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/) I've made use of some nice CSS container styling to make the iframe responsive. Also using the iframe class I can set the height to 120% which clips off the botton of the iframe display (which I want).  Here is the [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/0L5t42pg/2/)

Finally I'm trying to move the second Fiddle code into a jQuery dialog box.   I'm able to add the iframe so the content is responsive however it looks like the iframe class is not being applied and you can still see the bottom of the iframe display showing within the dialog. [Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/0L5t42pg/3/)

I need the dialog box to show the same as what's in Fiddle2 (responsive without the iframe footer)

...any ideas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<title>iframe</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="btn1">Button 1</button>

<div id="iFrameDiv" class="iframe-container">
    <iframe style="display:none;" id="myframe1" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMjJlYTYwODktYjU2NS00ZjZiLTg1YTktNDRlZjgzNzFmN2U5IiwidCI6ImRjOWNhZGMxLTJhZTItNGM0YS04MzIwLThlOTViMDAzNGI5NiJ9"  ></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>

$( "#myframe1" ).dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
resizable: true

});
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#myframe1" ).dialog( "open" );
});

.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 120%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery UI creates a dialog box, it copies the dialog content in a separated part of the DOM. Therefore your selector targetting the parent doesn't apply.

Check this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0h6a3epo/1/

I'm using the parent now as the dialog element, that applies the CSS.

Apart from that, I've added another jQuery line to show the iframe because jQuery UI was applying CSS `display:none;`by default.